# Google Analytics API Regex replace dimension data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Good morning,

I am looking to run a report in Google Sheets using the Google Analytics plug-in to return counts of Users for the Pages visited on our site.

Many of our URL's contain query-string data that I would like to strip out when returning the count. It's proving to be more difficult than I had hoped.

In Google Data Studio, I can do this easily by creating a calculated field with a regex-replace function around the page path. But I can't find a way to do this with the Google API plug-in for Google Sheets.

Can anyone help?

Rachael

Comment: Alas the API does not do that, you'd have to download all results and then run a custom function over the returned rows. Not hard in principle, but required bespoke programming (or clever use of spreadsheet functions) and depending on the size of your account the script might time out before it has processed all rows. Depending on your use case you can download the CSV from your Datastudio reports and insert them into a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for replying Eike, 
What a pain indeed...

I have already created an extra column in my google sheet to perform the regex replace function - I will now work on producing some reports based on my new calculated field, rather than the desired result, which would have obviously been to have the field calculated prior to data collection. 

Thanks again for the reply, maybe one day they'll allow for greater functionality within the core API.